# Heapify a Vector in C++

Tags: c++, vector

I am trying to heapify a given vector passed by reference to a function. The function takes a reference to a vector as an argument and heapifies it. I'm also trying to calculate how many positions in the vector changed value as compared to the starting point. I'd like to update this difference variable inside the function.

For each position in the new and old vector: if the positions have a different value: diff++

Here's What I Have:

```
void heapify(std::vector<int> &v, int &diff) 
{ 
    int max = diff;
    int l = 2 * diff + 1; 
    int r = 2 * diff + 2; 

    if (l < (int)v.size() && v[l] > v[diff])
        diff = l;

    if (r < (int)v.size() && v[r] > v[diff])
        diff = r;

    if (max != diff) {
       swap(v[max], v[diff]); 
       heapify(v, diff);
    }
}

int main()
{
    vector<int> v = {20, 19, 100, 2};
    int diff = 0;
    heapify(v, diff);
    cout << "Different in " << diff << " positions. Heap: ";
    for(int i: v)
    cout << i << ", ";
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

It is really close. A couple of glitches: for a one item vector, the contents shouldn't change. For a vector that's smallest to largest from 1 to 10, the difference is off by 2. For a really large random vector, the difference is off by 1.

Comment: Do you have to do this manually for an assignment? Because there is `<algorithm>`'s `std::make_heap()`.

Comment: <algorithm> std::make_heap() is not allowed.

Comment: that's a naive copy of max-heapify, which assumes that array index is 1-based. Also, the special cases require short-circuit `if`s

Comment: *For each position in the new and old vector:* -- Your code has no "new" and "old" vector.  It has a single vector and you're trying to figure out how to do this with one vector.  If you really had a "new" and "old" vector, the solution is trivial -- just compare the positions of each vector and see if `vector_old[i]` is equal to `vector_new[i]`.  I would even consider that a better solution anyway, since a heapify function should have only one purpose, and that is to heapify.  It shouldn't be in the statistics business.

Answer (score 0):

Using `std::make_heap`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v = {20, 19, 100, 2};
    std::make_heap(v.begin(), v.end());

    for(int i: v)
        std::cout << i << ", ";

    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

prints:

```
100, 19, 20, 2,
```

Comment: So, 2 hours before your answer, OP explicitly stated that they are not allowed to use `std::make_heap()`.